# ZKOSS: onClick() working differently for mouse click vs mouse tap

Tags: onclick, zk, zul

I am trying to disable double clicking a Help label which is an anchor to open the Help window.
    `<p:a id="helpClick" onClick="help()">
<label value="Help" style="color:#FFFFFF;" />
</p:a>`
When onClick() event is triggered once, either by Mouse click or Tapping the touchpad once, the help() method is being invoked.

```
void help() {
        flag = true;
        this.helpClick.setDisabled(true);
        Window popupWindow = null;
        popupWindow = (Window) Executions.createComponents("/zul/mainHelp.zul",
                null, null);
        this.popupWindow.setClosable(true);

        popupWindow.addEventListener("onClose", new EventListener() {

        void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
        this.helpClick.setDisabled(false);
        }
        });


    }
```

is the code which i added to handle the anchor tag with the id **helpClick**.
This is working perfectly fine when i use mouse clicks. For the first click, the window gets opened and simultaneously the Label is not taking any more click events.
When i try the same with mouse tap(using the touchpad), two single clicks are being triggered.
I have used onClick() to capture the event.
I am trying to disable the Label once it is clicked and the window is opened. Only after the window gets closed, i am enabling the label.
This is working totally fine when i use mouse clicks but not when i use tap.
With tapping, the label is taking multiple clicks which isnt the case with Mouse Click.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code it's difficult to provide advice but maybe you can capture the **onDoubleClick** event and ignore it or forward it to the to the same listener as your **onClick** event.
`... forward="onClick=onHelpClick,onDoubleClick=onHelpClick" ...`

After question edit:
It sounds like a bug if you can double click a disabled component. One thing you could try is set your link to **autodisable** `<p:a id="helpClick" onClick="help()" autodisable="self">` as per [A component documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/A#A)

Comment: i have updated the question by adding the code used.

Comment: I tried autoDisable at first. But it was giving me this error: **Method setAutodisable not found for class org.zkoss.zul.A**

Comment: @AvinashK which version of zk are you using? I checked and my version has A.setAutodisable(String). Also, what is the `p:` for, is that another namespace?

Comment: We are using an older verison of ZK. Looks like setAutoDisable() is not available in our version. Yeah, we used p as another namespace for zul. The following events are working fine **Single click, Single tap, Double click**. The problem is with **Double tap** where it is triggering two single click events even though we are disabling the label on first click.

Comment: @AvinashK Hmm, this sounds like a potential bug in zk (or a technical necessity). You could try to report it, or post it in their forum to find help. As a workaround, you could try to replace `onClick="help()"` with `onClick="if (!self.isDisabled()) help()"` (or put the check inside `help()`)

Comment: @MalteHartwig Magically, that worked. I tried different ways to fix it. Still wonder why it is not consistent between double click and double tap. Thanks for the workaround.